# How can I stop repetition if row data same in column using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code. I am newer in programming. If I made any mistake please help me to solve it. 
Thanks.

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="width:1300px; font-size:30px;" border="1px solid black">
                <tr>
                    <th>Reference No</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Total Price</th>
                </tr>
    <?php
    include("../db/db.php");
    $sql_cost_details="select b.* from lc_details a, cost_details b where b.reference_no=a.reference_no AND a.lc_details_no='$lc_no' order by reference_no ASC";
    $run_sql=mysqli_query($con, $sql_cost_details);
    $i=0;
    $total=0;
    while($row_cost_details=mysqli_fetch_array($run_sql)){
        $reference_no=$row_cost_details['reference_no'];
        $category=$row_cost_details['category'];
        $total_price=$row_cost_details['value'];
        $i++;
    ?>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td><?php echo $reference_no; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $category; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $total_price; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
```

It shows this type of result
[image: Current result]

Expected result is this:
[image: Want like this]

Comment: I want to show Reference No once if Reference No are same.

Comment: you have to do it using code

Comment: what is the output of your select query?

Comment: Could you help me to solve it?

Comment: SO isn't a free coding service, show us what you have tried in order to solve this.

Comment: Output is same as first image.

Comment: I already told that I am newer but why you down voted me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below which solve your problem:

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="width:1300px; font-size:30px;" border="1px solid black">
            <tr>
                <th>Reference No</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Total Price</th>
            </tr>
<?php
include("../db/db.php");
$sql_cost_details="select b.* from lc_details a, cost_details b where b.reference_no=a.reference_no AND a.lc_details_no='$lc_no' order by reference_no ASC";
$run_sql=mysqli_query($con, $sql_cost_details);
$i=0;
$total=0;
$prev = '';
while($row_cost_details=mysqli_fetch_array($run_sql)){
$reference_no=$row_cost_details['reference_no'];
    $category=$row_cost_details['category'];
    $total_price=$row_cost_details['value'];
    $i++;
?>
            <tr align="center">
                <td><?php if ($prev != $reference_no){ echo $reference_no; } ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $category; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $total_price; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
    $prev = $row_cost_details['reference_no']; 
    } ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Any code should be written in simple way. I have tried to give just simple solution.

Comment: while I understand that your solution is simple it will not be valuable for future visitors to SO because they will not take the time to look though the code to see the differences.

Comment: Ohh sure I  explain !!! I have declared variable $prev in my code and in the end of loop I assign value of $reference in $prev. and if Value of $prev is not equal to the value of $reference then It echo the value of $reference. $prev holds the value of  $reference in previous index of loop.